# Как сделать параметр метода глобальной переменной класса

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть метод, который вызывается при загрузке WPF страницы:

```
public FirstPage(User us)
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Ему в параметре с предыдущей страницы передаётся переменная us типа User.

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы параметр этого метода стал глобальной переменной класса, чтобы к us могли обращаться любые методы этого класса, а не только метод FirstPage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос кажется элементарным, поэтому если я верно трактую его, то и ответ тоже элементарный.

Сохранить в приватном [поле](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) данный объект у данного класса. Все методы класса могут использовать эту переменную

```
// private field
private User _us;

public FirstPage(User us)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _us = us;
}
```